# Missing argument 2 in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to log a user in and take them to a page that displays content based on a slug.

I get this error :

```
ErrorException in ApplicantLoginController.php line 21:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ApplicantLoginController::Login()
```

This is my controller :

```
public function Login(Request $request, $slug){
        //Validate the form
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'agree' => 'required'
        ]);

        //Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('applicant')->attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password] )) {

        $house = House::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
        return view('client.index')->withHouse($house);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));
    }
```

This is the route to the page I am taking them to after login :

```
Route::get('client/index/{slug}', ['as' => 'client.index', 'uses' => 'ClientRegistrationController@index']);
```

This are my login routes :

```
Route::get('client/login', 'Auth\ApplicantLoginController@ShowLoginForm')->name('client.login');
Route::post('/client/login', 'Auth\ApplicantLoginController@Login')->name('client.login.submit');
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

This the button that takes the user to the page with the content based on a slug

```
<a href="{{ url('client/index/'.$house->slug) }}" class="btn btn-success btn btn-block">Book now</a>
```

If the user is not logged in the page redirects to this login page:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('client.login.submit') }}">
                    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token()}}"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" required=""> I have read and accepted the <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="checkbox-terms-client">terms and condition</a>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">

                                </input>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="#">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have $slug declared in the post route:

```
Route::post('/client/login/{slug}', 'Auth\ApplicantLoginController@Login')->name('client.login.submit');
```

And change your form to add the parameter:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('client.login.submit', ['slug' => $slug]) }}">
```

Comment: I have done that, I get this error : ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: client.login.submit] [URI: client/login/{slug}].

Comment: Can you post the form where you're calling /client/login?

Comment: I have added the button that takes the user to the page with the information based on a slug. The user is required to login to access that page, when I attempt to login I get the error I posted.

Comment: You should add the parameter in the form route too... Check the edited answer.

Comment: I have updated my form with your solution but now there is this error : Undefined variable: slug ; pointing to my login form

Comment: If you are using the variable $slug in `Login` function, to get a `house` object, you need to get it by a parameter or an input. In this case, you are trying to send it as a parameter. So, you need to send it in the URL. If you don't have the variable in the form, what do you want to send to `Login` to be read as $slug?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand, could you please suggest something I can try..I must admit, I am a newbie in Laravel.

Comment: You need to know this variable `$slug` in `Login` right? So you have to send it to the controller function. How can you do that? One way is to send it in the route. So the route would be `/client/login/{slug}`. Then, you can call, for example: `/client/login/myslugstring`. This will be sent as the variable `$slug` in the function `Login`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, however, my route to the login form is /client/login/{slug} and in my controller I have the $slug variable in the login function but I get this error : Undefined variable: slug pointing to my login form. How should I properly define the $slug variable in my function?